# DevExpress WPF GridContol Export Very Large Data to Excel File

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, export-to-excel, large-data

I'm trying to export a DevExpress GridControl with more than 2 millions rows,
then error 'OutOfMemory exception' appears .

**What is the best way to export and handle this?**

this my code

retrieve from DataTable:

```
public async void Get_Report()
        {
            try
            {
                myGridControl.ItemsSource = await Get_Report_from_DataTable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

then export to excel:

```
private void btn_Excel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                XlsxExportOptionsEx options = new XlsxExportOptionsEx() { UnboundExpressionExportMode = DevExpress.Export.UnboundExpressionExportMode.AsFormula, LayoutMode = LayoutMode.Table };
                options.BeforeExportTable += options_BeforeExportTable;
                
                myGridControl_view.ExportToXlsx("Large Report.xlsx", options);
        //This the view of GridControl
                Process.Start("Large Report.xlsx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        void options_BeforeExportTable(BeforeExportTableEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Table.Style.Name = XlBuiltInTableStyleId.Medium9;
        }
```

Comment: Divide data into multiple spreadsheets instead of one spreadsheet.

Comment: I just knew the maximum number of rows that Excel can handle is 1,048,576 rows,

Comment: I decided to divide the result to multiple excel files as @jdweng said. just for the benefit, you can use this code `MyView.ShowRibbonPrintPreview(this);` to print or export the view to any format you want